# Ansible to call the rule using become for Linux, no become for windows

Tags: ansible

I have below code to call the `puppet-agent` install role, this works for Linux, but, when I use a Windows machine it is giving error for the `become` line.

How can I update below code for both Linux and Windows. include become for Linux and exclude `become` for Windows?

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  roles:
    - puppet-agent
```

**Error message**

```
 fatal: [winhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The powershell shell family is
    incompatible with the sudo become plugin"}
```

Comment: Share the error output.

Comment: @JiriB updated post with error message

Comment: Instead of setting `become: yes`, try setting `become` to a boolean expression like `become: "{{ ansible_system == 'Linux' }}"`

Comment: getting this error: `The field 'become' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_system' is undefined`

Comment: @sfgroups note you have to  gather facts to get `ansible_system`. So if you have something like `gather_facts; no` you should remove it.

Comment: added the `gather_facts` to `yes`. still same error message.

Comment: I assume you did some websearching, did https://www.mail-archive.com/ansible-project@googlegroups.com/msg53740.html not work? If so, can you add that to your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would be worth trying, although I do not have a Windows box at disposal to test it, is to fully [`omit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional) the `become` directive if you are on Windows:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  
  roles:
    - role: puppet-agent
      become: "{{ true if ansible_system == 'Linux' else omit }}"
```

Comment: getting this error `The field 'become' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_system' is undefined`

Comment: mhm indeed, `become` on the play level happens before the fact gathering. You can overcome it by moving it at role level. See updated answer.